# Creating an empty dataframe in R with column names stored in two separate lists

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two separate lists containing column names of a new dataframe [df](/questions/tagged/df) to be created.

```
fixed <- list("a", "b")
variable <- list("a1", "b1", "c1")
```

How do I proceed so as to make the column names of [df](/questions/tagged/df) appear in the order [a](/questions/tagged/a)[b](/questions/tagged/b)[a1](/questions/tagged/a1)[b1](/questions/tagged/b1)[c1](/questions/tagged/c1)

Answer (score 6):

Probabaly, `unlist` both lists, concatenate and subset the data

```
df[unlist(c(fixed, variable))]
```

If there are additional elements in the list that are not as column names in 'df', use `intersect`

```
df[intersect(unlist(c(fixed, variable)), names(df))]
 a a1 c1
1 7  8  1
2 3  1  5
3 8  5  4
4 7  5  6
5 2  5  6
```

---

If it is a null data.frame, we could do

```
v1 <- unlist(c(fixed, variable))
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(numeric(), nrow = 0,
       ncol = length(v1), dimnames = list(NULL, v1)))
str(df)
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ a : num 
 $ b : num 
 $ a1: num 
 $ b1: num 
 $ c1: num
```

Or another option is

```
df <-  data.frame(setNames(rep(list(0), length(v1)), v1))[0,]
> str(df)
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ a : num 
 $ b : num 
 $ a1: num 
 $ b1: num 
 $ c1: num
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c('a', 'd2', 'c', 'a1', 'd1', 'c1', 'e1')
set.seed(24)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:9, 5 * length(v1),
    replace = TRUE), ncol = length(v1), dimnames = list(NULL, v1)))
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Throws an error saying 'Error in `[.data.frame`(df, unlist(c(fixed, variable))) :  undefined columns selected'

Comment: @AbhishekChowdhury ok, have you tried the updated one `df[intersect(unlist(c(fixed, variable)), names(df))]`

Comment: I did, but it returns an empty dataframe

Comment: @AbhishekChowdhury well, what is `df`  Is it a data.frame or matrix or something else.  I would appreciate a reproducible example instead. thanks

Comment: I initialized df as:     df <- data.frame().  Then I created the two lists as mentioned in the example. That's all I did.

Comment: @AbhishekChowdhury So, it is a null dataset.  I was thinking that you already have a full dataset

Comment: No, df is an empty dataframe, to which I want to add column names in the order that I mentioned in my question. Could you edit your answer accordingly?